# How to make a PredicateBuilder Not

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

recently I've been working with the PredicateBuilder class [(shown here)](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to help generate an expression tree.  The True, And, and Or methods provided work fine.  However, I would also like to use a Not method, and so far my attempt at one gets me the error

```
Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration.
```

Here is said attempt:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
            (Expression.Not(Expression.Invoke(expr, expr.Parameters.Cast<Expression>())));
    }
```

Any thoughts?

NB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oop, just about had it.  I wasn't giving parameters to the outer .Lambda function:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
            (Expression.Not(Expression.Invoke(expr, expr.Parameters.Cast<Expression>())), expr.Parameters);
    }
```